# How can i create detail page in asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code to create master-detail relationship in asp.net core. i have a kendo UI Grid but i wanted to pass data to the detail page of the selected record.

Product Controller look like as follows

GetProduct Action

```
    [HttpGet]    
        public async Task<IActionResult> Getproduct()    
        {    
            var product= await ProductService.Getproduct();    
            return Json(products);    
        }
```

Detail Action

```
public IActionResult Detail()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@inject IProductService productService

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductList>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
   {
   columns.Bound(p => p.productCode).Width(120);
   columns.Bound(p => p.productCode).ClientTemplate( "<a href='" + Url.Action("Detail", "Product") +        "/#= productCode #'" + ">Details</a>");
   columns.Bound(p => p.productName).Width(120);

})

  .Groupable()
  .ToolBar(t => t.Search())
  .Sortable()
  .PersistSelection()
  .Filterable()
  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
  .ButtonCount(5)
  .Refresh(true)
  .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20 }))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Custom()
  .Transport(transport => transport
  .Read(read => read.Action("Getproduct", "Product")
                  )) ))
```

I wanted to create a link to a detail page and show the selected record information in detail.cshtm, I'm able to pass the productCode with the url as http://localhost:XXX/Product/product/Detail/800013 but I need help displaying Product Name in detail page, I used ClientTemplate as follows but i need some help displaying other information's

```
columns.Bound(p => p.productCode).ClientTemplate("<a href='" +  Url.Action("Detail", "product") + "/#= productCode #'" +  ">Show Details</a>");
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I need some help"? What are you seeing? Is there anything in the console (F12). Perhaps this would be better asked on the Kendo forum. Regardless of the forum you'll need to be more specific

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid i have `Getproduct` which gets all product info which is fine my problem is display a single record info in a detail page,  do i have to re-write  detail page action `public IActionResult Detail() to get row detail using productCode?
`

Comment: You can certainly go that route (calling an MVC action), but a better approach IMO is to popup a modal with the details as shown here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command?_ga=2.146460340.144172879.1580832359-2127740456.1564504565